# Do I need a stairway for egress from a balcony that's off a second floor bedroom?

Tags: egress

I have a rental cottage.  It has two stories with a bedroom and bath on the second floor that are accessed by spiral staircase. The bedroom opens onto a 4'x13' balcony which is 16 feet above a courtyard.  Does Massachusetts building code require a stairway from the balcony to the ground?

Comment: I don't know about code, but speaking as someone who sat with my coffee on such a staircase for the first time this morning (we've added an upstairs sun room and the stairs to it were built yesterday) I recommend you build them. A four foot balcony is pretty small and the stairs will make it a nicer place to be. Also when you want to get large things in and out the spiral stairs will make you crazy. Stairs are cheaper than balconies, so build them.

Answer (score 3):

Spiral staircases are allowed if they meet the specs (780 CMR 5311.5.8.1), but as with any bedroom, you have to have a second means of egress in an emergency (Sec. 5310). This can be a window in the bedroom, provided it meets the requirements. I don't see any requirement that a window be under a certain height from the ground. I recommend calling the local building inspector to be sure--your county or city may have more stringent requirements than the state building code.